# Logistic regression with E-net regularization produces different set of weights with each run

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, binary-classification, elastic-net

I am currently trying to make a model to classify brain tumor patients by incidence of epilepsy using a combination of variables extracted from clinical records, and radiomics features from segmented MR images. In total there are 1396 features obtained from 53 patients, which have been min max scaled and z-score normalized (there were some categorical variables which have been one hot encoded). Based on existing literature in the field, I opted to use a logistic regression with an elastic net regularization to select the important features.

First, I tried to find the optimal alpha and L1 ratio from a set of values, using stratified  kfold validation (there were more negatives than positives):

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)
def scores_cv(model):
    scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, scoring='roc_auc', cv = skf)
    return(scores)

alphas = [0.001, 0.005, 0.001 ,0.005, 0.009, 0.01, 0.1, 0.5, 1] #
l1_ratios = [1, 0.97 ,0.95, 0.93, 0.9, 0.5, 0.1, 0.01]
cv_elastic = [scores_cv(SGDClassifier(loss="log_loss", penalty="elasticnet",alpha = alpha,l1_ratio = l1_ratio)).mean() 
            for (alpha, l1_ratio) in product(alphas, l1_ratios)]

matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12.0, 6.0)
idx = list(product(alphas, l1_ratios))
p_cv_elastic = pd.Series(cv_elastic, index = idx)
p_cv_elastic.plot(title = "Validation - Just Do It")
plt.xlabel("alpha - l1_ratio")
plt.ylabel("roc_auc")
print('alpha, lambda and error value, respectively = '+ str(p_cv_elastic[p_cv_elastic == p_cv_elastic.max()]))
```

Then, I fit a logistic regression model with the best hyperparameters on all the data, and looked for non-zero coefficients in the model.

```
enetlog = SGDClassifier(loss="log_loss", penalty="elasticnet",alpha = 0.1,l1_ratio = 0.93).fit(X,y)
print('accuracy:' +str(enetlog.score(X,y)))
y_pred = enetlog.predict(X)
print('stratified kfold accuracies:'+ str(scores_cv(enetlog)))

cm = confusion_matrix(y, y_pred, labels=enetlog.classes_)
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm,
                              display_labels=enetlog.classes_)
disp.plot()
plt.show()
enet_results = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(list(X.columns),list(np.transpose(enetlog.coef_)))),columns=['Variable Name','Linear Regression Coefficient']) #if pipeline not used, it should be regr.coef_
enet_results = enet_results.sort_values(by=['Linear Regression Coefficient'])
enet_results = enet_results.loc[~((enet_results['Linear Regression Coefficient'] == 0) )]
enet_results['Linear Regression Coefficient'] = enet_results['Linear Regression Coefficient'].astype(float)
ax = enet_results.plot.barh(x='Variable Name', y='Linear Regression Coefficient', rot=0,figsize=(10, 15),fontsize = 12)
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0],label_type='center')
```

The problem is most of the time I run the loop to find the best model, I end up with a different set of hyperparameters/maximum score. For instance the graph of metric against hyperparameter pair can look like this:
[image: tuning 1]

Then in another run it would look like this:

[image: tuning 2]
The best alpha, l1 ratio pair will usually be around 0.1,0.9 or 0.1,1. Then, when I pick the set of hyperparameters to construct the logistic regression model, there is often a different set of variables with nonzero coefficients in the model. Sometimes the model will have as low as 8 nonzero coefficients, and other times as high as 40.
Changing max_iter in either step (I tried up to max_iter = 10 000 000)does not seem to solve the inconsistencies between runs. I suspect the problem is a lack of data (only 53 samples), but I'm not sure if there are any other causes.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `In total there are 1396 features obtained from 53 patients, which have been min max scaled and z-score normalized` These are contradictory. If you do z-scoring, it will undo min-max scaling, and if you do min-max scaling, it will undo z-scoring.

Comment: `In total there are 1396 features obtained from 53 patients, which have been min max scaled and z-score normalized` That's a huge number of features for how many instances you have. Luck is going to play a role in what features you find are important. Whether that's a problem depends in some respect on what your output is - are you trying to find features in order to make predictions, or is the set of features the important output?

Comment: I mentioned minmax scaling for transparency's sake, as the raw data is un-normalized, and I didn't know which model/loss function I was going to use at first. I did the z-score normalization since from what I've read, Elastic net has issues handling data that isn't z-score normalized. For now you can assume that the data is just z-score normalized. @NickODell

Comment: At this stage I'm just trying to select for the important features, then I'll make another model that uses those features to perform a binary classification.  I do understand that that is a large number of features, but it's not unusual for radiomics studies in this field to extract >1000 features from the clinical and imaging data, then select for only the relevant features. @NickODell